# Is there a single word for a document containing an individual's contact information?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single noun to indicate a document (or web page) that contains a person's contact information (phone, email, etc.).

The context is a navigation element on a personal website, for example:

> Home | Bio | Contact Page

I want to substitute the text "Contact Page" with the word I'm seeking.

Archaic, formal or loaned words are perfectly acceptable, even desired. The tone of the website is humorous.

A word that has a metaphorically connected meaning (similar to the way "Home" is understood to mean "The Home Page"), though less desirable, is still acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with "Contact"? That's what seems to be used on many (maybe even most) sites.

Comment: Nothing at all's wrong with it! I use "Contact" regularly, and may use it as a fallback if I can't think of something here. For aesthetic reasons, for this site, I wanted to do something that was a little bit off-the-beaten-path.

Comment: *Contact* is the conventional term for the purpose, and that's how it is currently understood by everyone, in the context. For more, try ux.SE

Comment: If you don't mind a bit older word that means one place where you store all of your contact information, ["Rolodex"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rolodex) might work. (Note that it is a trademarked name.)

Comment: I appreciate the nudges toward a mass market-friendly term for the link text. I agree that "Contact" would be correct in 99.999% of all cases. However, this website employs an unconventional narrative voice, so an unconventional word is more befitting -- and fun.

Comment: If you're going for unconventional or humorous, how about "ASL" - Age, Sex, Location?

Answer (score 2):

You could use "my card", making a joking metaphor of a card containing contact details (these days normally a "business card", but gentlemen had cards in the days when gentlemen would not be so crass as to discuss business).

Most often used is either "Contact" or "Contact Us"/"Contact Me"/"Contact [Your Name]".

Comment: I do like the ring of "my card" or even "calling card" ...

Comment: You could have fun with it. I'd avoid "card" on its own as a bit oblique, though if it was vCard or RDF/XML vCard format, then I'd be tempted.

Answer (score 1):

One idea just came to mind: *dossier*.

Not quite right, but may spur a better idea!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but *dossier* sounds like something MI6 has about you, rather than something you put up about yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going down the straight and conventional? I'd suggest the slightly odd sounding, but highly standardized term **about**.

Head to any major page and if I can't find a straight up *contact us* link, then this is where I'll go to next for that kind of detail.

If you're going for something a bit left-field, how about **particulars**?

I'd associate it more with personal info (height/weight/etc) - here's an example of a [personal particulars card](http://vrroom.naa.gov.au/records/?ID=24830) from the National Archives of Australia - but I wouldn't be too surprised to have contact details stashed in it.

You'd *generally* need to state what kind of particulars but depending on audience, they might get the idea that that page is full of 'detail-like information' which could be enough if the other links are clearly for other things.

Comment: I particularly like *particulars*.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with **Dope** or **Lowdown** to mean information, depending on the tone of your site.

You might also consider **Interface**.

Answer (score 1):

How about *linkage, passage, access, doorway, details, curriculum*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bland, but "Profile" seems to me fairly standard practice.